# How to find rows that have one equal value and one different value from the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
ID       Number      Revision
x         y           0
x         y           1
z         w           0
a         w           0
a         w           1
b         m           0
b         m           0
```

I need to return rows that for the same Number thare are more then one ID with the same Revision.Number can be "Null" and I don't need those values.
The output should be:

```
z         w           0
a         w           0
```

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT a.id,a.number,a.revision,
FROM table a INNER JOIN 
             (SELECT id, number, revision FROM table where number > '0' 
              GROUP BY number HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
             ) b ON  a.revision = b.revision AND a.id != b.id
```

A little addition- I have rows in my table with the same Number, ID and Revision- I don't need those rows in my query to be displayed!

It is not working! Please help me to figure out how to fix it.
Thanks.

Comment: `I need to return rows that for the same Number thare are more then one ID with the same Revision.` It's a little bit difficult to understand. Please ask clearly

Comment: I think they mean: find all rows such that there is more than one row that holds these properties: the number column is the same, the revision column is the same, but where the id columns differ

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I am new to this forum!

Comment: I want to return rows that match the following criteria: For the same  Number and revision there are more than one ID in the table. I hope that I have explained it better this time

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t.Id,s.number,t.revision
from (Select number,count(*) 'c'
     from table t1 
     where revision=0 
     group by number 
     having count(*) > 1 
   ) s join table t on t.number= s.number
where revision = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not that far away with your query:

```
SELECT a.id,a.number,a.revision
FROM table a 
JOIN (
    -- multiple id for the same number and revision 
    SELECT number, revision 
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY number, revision 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) b 
    ON  a.revision = b.revision 
   AND a.number = b.number
```

Untested, but you should get the idea. If your sql-server is a resent version you can solve this with OLAP functions as well.

To filter out rows where the whole row is duplicated we can select only unique rows via group by and having:

```
SELECT a.id,a.number,a.revision
FROM table a 
JOIN (
    -- multiple id for the same number and revision 
    SELECT number, revision 
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY number, revision 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) b 
    ON  a.revision = b.revision 
   AND a.number = b.number
GROUP BY a.id,a.number,a.revision
HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
```

Comment: Hi Lennart, thank you so much. Now I have a new problem: it turns out that I have also rows with the same Number, ID and revision and in this case I don't want tha row to be displayed at all

Comment: @user3773476 What do you mean exactly? Say id, num, rev are: a|1|0 ; a|1|0 ; b|1|0. What should be the result?

Comment: I mean that I can have two rows with the same value of all three.       1  1  1                                                                   1  1  1   because I have another unique field in my table. If for the same Number with the same Revision I don't have more than one ID I don't need those rows at all in my query result.

Comment: Thank you very much! You halped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Another simple approach:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  b.id, b.Number, b.Revision
FROM       tbl a
INNER JOIN tbl b
ON         a.ID != b.ID  AND  a.Number = b.Number  AND  a.Revision = b.Revision;
```

This is tested in MySql 5, syntax might differ slightly.